# CodeIgniter - form validatoin add simple value test

Tags: codeigniter

I use Codeigniter 3 and form validation. I didn't find in doc, but is there a way to add a simple value test as error ?

I have my form validation :

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');
```

This data is from my post form, but I want to add an error from a value like :

```
if ($other_field != 'test') {
      // how to add a custom message without callback nor fields
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_field_here', 'Custom error', 'required');
}
```

Is there a kind of simple way ?

Comment: You can use validation callbacks for  your-own-validation-methods, read : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Yes but a callback depends of a field. I just want to test one value, not a field.

Comment: so to validate non form data read this ; https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

Comment: form validation library works on normally on form fields  in your case you have to add input type  hidden in your fronted form

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this if you want **custom message** for specific field :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('no_field_here', 'Custom error', 'required',array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.'));
```

or else ,if you want give common message for **required** fields,

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'required');
```

Hope you understand.